# gnome dash to panel: remove applications label

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using Ubuntu with gnome and the dash-to-panel extension. On the bottom left, I have a 'Application' with a bottom arrow next to it, which is not clickable. Next to it is the applications icon (9 dots) since I opted for the 'show applications icon' in the settings. How to get rid of the 'Application' label, which has no use and eats space?

[image: Application]

Comment: "On the top left, I have a 'Applications' with a bottom arrow ..." - maybe you told about "Activities"? What you want to remove "Activities" (with arrow) or "Applications" (9 dots)?

Comment: Sorry I meant bottom left. See screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/A2XPXR0). This is my bottom left, and the word 'Applications' is meaningless and should be removed. Applying the solution you gave in your answer below doesn't solve this issue.